# jQuery Document ready function conflicting with window onload function

Tags: jquery

I have the following codes.
Window onload function is for menu button display for mobile devices instead of the full menu display.

Document ready function is for full width responsive slider.

```
window.onload = function() {
var nav = document.getElementById('nav'); 
var navItem = nav.getElementsByTagName('li');
//is it floated?
var floated = navItem[0].currentStyle ? el.currentStyle['float'] :  document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(navItem[0],null).getPropertyValue('float');

if (floated != 'left') {
    var collapse = document.getElementById('nav-collapse');

    //toggle class utility function
    var classToggle = function( element, tclass ) {
        var classes = element.className,
        pattern = new RegExp( tclass );
        hasClass = pattern.test( classes );
        //toggle the class
        classes = hasClass ? classes.replace( pattern, '' ) : classes + ' ' + tclass;
        element.className = classes.trim();
    };

    classToggle(nav, 'hide');
    classToggle(collapse, 'active');
    collapse.onclick = function() {
        classToggle(nav, 'hide');
        return false;
    }
}
}

$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('#full-width-slider').royalSlider({
arrowsNav: true,
loop: false,
keyboardNavEnabled: true,
controlsInside: false,
imageScaleMode: 'fill',
arrowsNavAutoHide: false,
autoScaleSlider: true, 
autoScaleSliderWidth: 960,     
autoScaleSliderHeight: 350,
controlNavigation: 'bullets',
thumbsFitInViewport: false,
navigateByClick: true,
startSlideId: 0,
autoPlay: false,
transitionType:'move',
globalCaption: false,
fullscreen: {
    // fullscreen options go gere
    enabled: true,
    nativeFS: true
},
autoPlay: {
    // autoplay options go gere
    enabled: true,
    pauseOnHover: true
},
deeplinking: {
  enabled: true,
  change: false
},
/* size of all images http://help.dimsemenov.com/kb/royalslider-jquery-plugin-faq/adding-width-and-height-properties-to-images */
imgWidth: 1400,
imgHeight: 680
 });
});
```

The Html

```
<nav role="navigation">
                  <a href="#nav" class="nav-collapse" ><img src="images/btn_menu.jpg" alt="menu" id="nav-collapse"></a>
                  <ul class="nav" id="nav">
                       <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                       <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
                       <li><a href="compliant-reporting.html">Compliant Reporting</a></li>
                       <li><a href="setup-training.html">Setup &amp; Training</a></li>
                       <li><a href="demo-videos.html">Demo Videos</a></li>
                       <li><a href="events-calendar.html">Events Calendar</a></li>
                       <li><a href="contact-us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                  </ul>
                  </nav>
```

Both javascript and jQuery are in the same file default.js  The window.onload is working but the slider script is not working. If I remove window.onload then slider is working.

They are conflicting. Any help?

Comment: why not put everything in the document ready function, and detect mobile devices and then executing different code?

Comment: *"They are conflicting."* In what way? What's the symptom? What do you expect to happen, and what's happening instead? What have you done to try to work out what the problem is?

Comment: Paramasivan, if you don't explain the problem, you're not going to get useful help.

Comment: Both javascript and jquery are in default.js   The window.onload is working but the slider script is not working. If I remove window.onload then slider is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default.js is a common file.  It contains form validation code, jQuery tabs, jQuery date picker, etc. which are used on other pages.

I put only the window.onload function and document.ready function  in a separate file and included that file.

It works now!

Thanks for all.

Answer (score -2):

`window.onload` is, by all intents and purposes, the same as `$.ready`*, which means they will both execute on any device.

If you truly want something to run on mobile and not desktop (and vice versa), you must use [some kind of mobile detection](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/download/javascript) and do:

```
if ($.browser.mobole) {
    your mobile code here
} else {
    your desktop code here
}
```

* experts: no, they are not actually the same.

Comment: They're not even *close* to the same. One happens fairly soon after the page basically appears to the user. The other happens a lot later.

Comment: Much aware of the difference myself, but in the code provided, the two closures execute in a very similar manner.

Comment: window.onload is purely a javascript function such as getElementById('nav')

Comment: If anyone else is interested in arguing the specifics of jQuery while ignoring my U+002A, you can [look up the code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L70) and see what it is doing.